# gVim how to set guifont bold attribute

Tags: windows, vim, fonts

I am using gvim 7.3 on Windows 7. I want to set the "Courier_New" font in bold style.
How to do that? I tried the following but it failed.

```
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2")
    set guifont=Inconsolata\ 12
  elseif has("gui_macvim")
    set guifont=Menlo\ Regular:h14
  elseif has("gui_win32")
    set guifont=Courier_New\ Bold:h12:cANSI
  endif
endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An almost exactly identical example is available at the bottom of `:help 'guifont'`:

```
:set guifont=courier_new:h12:w5:b:cRUSSIAN
```

so the following should do what you want:

```
:set guifont=courier_new:h12:b:cANSI
```

*Always* start with `:help`.

Additionaly, you can use `:set guifont=*` to open the font choosing dialog, select your font, and then use `:set guifont?` to see how the option was set.